# Change the variable in one column to a another variable

Tags: r, match

I have data in the form

```
InputID   matchID1   matchID2   matchID3   matchID4
4:560812  6:80321    5:16412   13:349812  2:154123
12:45123  16:12341   4:54323   12:561342  3:146542
5:872341  7:890750   5:198273  1:15411    2:788972
8:4098223 1:89471    3:947123  12:407123  19:498723
9:1289037 11:1023948 7:64237   1:4239837  3:364123
```

I have another file with the form:

```
InputID   rsID
4:560812  rs501239
12:45123  rs740123
9:1289037 rs834019
5:872341  rs903841
8:4098223 rs10983
```

The Input-RSID file is not necessarily in the same order as the first file. I would like to have an output file where I replace the input IDs with the rsID for just the first column. I would like to keep all the other IDs the same. There is potential that some of the input IDs are matchIDs for a different input, but I would not like to replace those.

```
InputID   matchID1   matchID2   matchID3   matchID4
rs501239  6:80321    5:16412   13:349812  2:154123
rs740123  16:12341   4:54323   12:561342  3:146542
rs903841  7:890750   5:198273  1:15411    2:788972
rs10983   1:89471    3:947123  12:407123  19:498723
rs834019  11:1023948 7:64237   1:4239837  3:364123
```

How would I go about doing this in R, using data frames? Or maybe not in R?

Comment: Assuming there are two data.frames, just use `merge()`. If the column with the IDs is named in "InputID" in both, you'll have no problems.

Comment: If you have two dataframes, `df1`and `df2`, I think that  `df1$InputID <- df2$rsID` achieves what you want.

Comment: @RHertel, they aren't in the same order though, that is the problem

Comment: How should the entries be reordered?

Comment: File1 and File2 do not necessarily have the Input_SNP in the same order. The output order doesn't matter. No worries, I got it answered =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the function `merge` to first join the second data frame to the first one lke this :

```
DF <- merge(DF2,DF1,by="InputID")
```

then have the first column (wich would be the InputID one) removed like this:

```
DF <- DF[-1]
```

and last, call the new first column "InputID"

```
colnames(DF)[1] <- "InputID"
```

Hope it works!